# How to cancel an observable from a different process

Tags: rxjs

Suppose you have a batch job running in a process. You're using observables as the implementation.

Now you want to introduce an API to the client. Such that, the user is able to cancel/stop that running batch job. The API request would be in another process handled by your web server.

I'm thinking of setting a flag in the database that the API can set and subsequently the batch job process can read to communicate the cancel signal. Is it possible for the batch job process to periodically check whether that signal is set?

```
  const ob = from([1,2,3]);
  ob.pipe(mergeMap(i => {
    // do something
    return of(i);
  }, undefined, 1);
```

Maybe perhaps the second parameter of mergeMap does that?

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this with RxJS is to create a subject to is responsible for cancelling the batch job.

```
const cancelBatchJob$ = new Subject();
const ob$ = from([1,2,3]);
ob$.pipe(
  mergeMap(i => doBatchJobWith(i)),
  takeUntil(cancelBatchJob$)
).subscribe(
  results => console.log(results.complete)
);
```

Now if you want to cancel the batch job, you just emit to the `cancelBatchJob$`

```
cancelBatchJob$.next();
```